# How can I escape all code within <code></code> tags to allow people to post code?

Tags: php, escaping

What I want to do is to allow users to post code if they need to, so it is viewable and it doesn't render. For example:

```
<span>
<div id="hkhsdfhu"></div>
</span>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Should be turned into:

```
&lt;span&gt;
&lt;div id="hkhsdfhu"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;
```

Only if it is wrapped in `<code></code>` tags. Right now I am using the following function to allow only certain HTML tags and escape any other tags:

```
function allowedHtml($str) {
$allowed_tags = array("b", "strong", "i", "em");
$sans_tags = str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("&lt;","&gt;"), $str);
$regex = sprintf("~&lt;(/)?(%s)&gt;~", implode("|",$allowed_tags));
$with_allowed = preg_replace($regex, "<\\1\\2>", $sans_tags);
return $with_allowed;
}
```

However, if a user wraps their code in `<code></code>` tags and it contains any of the allowed tags in my function above, those tags will render instead of being escaped. How can I make it where anything in `<code></code>` tags gets escaped (or just the `<` and `>` turned into `&lt;` and `&gt;`)? I know about `htmlentities()` but I don't want to do that to the whole post, only stuff inside `<code></code>` tags.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single `preg_replace()` function with the [e modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to execute an `htmlenteties()` function on everything it finds within `<code>` tags

EDITED

```
function allowedHtml($str) {
  $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
  $allowed_tags = array("b", "strong", "i", "em", "code");
  foreach ($allowed_tags as $tag) {
    $str = preg_replace("#&lt;" . $tag . "&gt;(.*?)&lt;/" . $tag . "&gt;#i", "<" . $tag . ">$1</" . $tag . ">", $str);
  }
  return $str;
}

$reply = allowedHtml($_POST['reply']);
$reply = preg_replace("#\<code\>(.+?)\</code\>#e", "'<code>'.htmlentities('$1', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</code>'", $reply);
$reply = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $reply);
```

Rewrote your `allowedHtml()` function and added a `str_replace()` at the end.

It's tested and should now work perfectly :)

UPDATED - NEW SOLUTION

```
function convertHtml($reply, $revert = false) {
  $specials = array("**", "*", "_", "-");
  $tags = array("b", "i", "u", "s");

  foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    $open = "<" . $tag . ">";
    $close = "</" . $tag . ">";

    if ($revert == true) {
      $special = $specials[$key];
      $reply = preg_replace("#" . $open . "(.+?)" . $close . "#i", $special . "$1" . $special, $reply);
    }
    else {
      $special = str_replace("*", "\*", $specials[$key]);
      $reply = preg_replace("#" . $special . "(.+?)" . $special . "#i", $open . "$1" . $close, $reply);
    }
  }

  return $reply;
}

$reply = htmlentities($reply, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$reply = convertHtml($reply);

$reply = preg_replace("#[^\S\r\n]{4}(.+?)(?!.+)#i", "<pre><code>$1</code></pre>", $reply);
$reply = preg_replace("#\</code\>\</pre\>(\s*)\<pre\>\<code\>#i", "$1", $reply);

$reply = nl2br($reply);
$reply = preg_replace("#\<pre\>\<code\>(.*?)\</code\>\</pre\>#se", "'<pre><code>'.convertHtml(str_replace('<br />', '', '$1'), true).'</code></pre>'", $reply);
```

Discussed another solution, and the above code will fix that. It works just like the Stack Overflow html conversion, which means that ** becomes bold, * becomes italic, _ becomes underlined and - is "strikethrough". On top of that, all lines starting with 4 or more spaces will be output as code

Comment: Hmm, it still didn't work. I added `<code>` as an allowed tag and it renders properly now but the other allowed tags are still being rendered (`<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<em>`). I used your exact code as above.

Comment: @Nathan - That's weird... do you have the $reply = allowedHtml($reply); line above the preg_replace() function like my code?

Comment: Yeah, [see this screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/bAKtjc3G).  Do you think it could have something to do with any of the other code I have in the script? (you can see it all in the screenshot)

Comment: @Nathan - Rewrote your allowedHtml() function and added a str_replace() at the end. Tried it out, and should now work perfectly :)

Comment: PHP is getting on my nerves right now LOL. It's being weird. This should work but it isn't for some reason. Since you tested it and it worked for you, it really should work. I'm beginning to think I'm not doing something right. But I'm using the [exact same code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/864479/) that you gave me.

Comment: @Nathan - did you replace your allowedHtml() function with mine?

Comment: I have decided to just not allow any HTML to render so it'll be easier to have the code thing. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: @Nathan - Ok, weird =/ tested it out with the exact same text you used and it worked perfectly for me.. must be something else in your coding screwing it up

Comment: @Nathan - Sounds like a good idea. but if you really would like bold text etc. you could always do it the same way it's done here on stack overflow. I think the problem is the use of actual html tags, so if you'ld use special characters or bbcode I think you would be able to go around whatever's causing this

Comment: @Nathan - Oh wait... do you do anything with the text when you retrieve from the database?

Comment: I just use `nl2br()` when I retreive it from the database, but do you know how I could do bold, italic, strike like this: `**bold**` `_italic_` `-strike-` It would just be some regexp right?

Comment: Wow, this is great! Fantastic job :) Do I do this when I insert it into the database or retrieve it?

Comment: @Nathan - Thanks. Do it when you insert it :) Then you don't have to worry about having dangerous code in your database, and when you retrieve it you only have to put e.g. $get['text'] :)

Comment: It works perfectly! It works just as it would with HTML, but better because users that aren't experienced with HTML (I'm sure) rather use markdown. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Nathan - If you later on would like to add more options, like links, images, lists etc I just found this plugin http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/ Requires some extra work, so unless you really want extended features, I'ld recommend you to stick with my code :) Good luck!

Comment: @Nathan - Also, made an important update to the code (used a lazy hack in the last preg_replace function which I forgot to replace with the new and better solution) so please update yours too. Only updated the last line

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, Tom. I updated the code on my system. It works awesomely :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better off working directly with the dom rather than using regular expressions to parse out allowed tags.  For example to traverse the dom and escape content in `<code>` tags, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($postHtml);
$codeNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('code')->item(0);
$escapedCode = htmlspecialchars($codeNode->nodeValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks interesting. I've never used `DOMDocument`, so thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace).  Just make sure you call this function before you call your `allowedHtml` function so the tags are already replaced.

```
<?php

$post = <<<EOD
I am a person writing a post
How can I write this code?

Example:

<code>
<span>
<div id="hkhsdfhu"></div>
</span>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</code>

Pls help me...
EOD;
```

---

```
$post = preg_replace('/<code>(.*?)<\/code>/ise',
                     "'<code>' . htmlspecialchars('$1') . '</code>'",
                      $post);

var_dump($post);
```

### Result:

```
string(201) "I am a person writing a post
How can I write this code?

Example:

<code>
&lt;span&gt;
&lt;div id=\&quot;hkhsdfhu\&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;
</code>

Pls help me..."
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, but the `<b>` tag still rendered: http://screencast.com/t/H15sm62igbT1 Here's the code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/862856/ Is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked over your `allowedHtml` function too quickly and didn't realize you were replacing all tags with htmlentities first and then converting the entities back to `<` and `>` for the allowed tags.  I'm thinking now of different ways to make them both work together.

Comment: @Nathan - Have a look at my solution instead

Comment: I have decided to just not allow any HTML to render so it'll be easier to have the code thing. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=<code>)(.*?)(?=<\/code>)/si','escape_code',$str);

function escape_code($matches) {

    $tags = array('b','strong','i','em');
    // declare the tags in this array

    $allowed = implode('|',$tags);
    $match = htmlentities($matches[0],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
    return preg_replace('~&lt;(/)?('.$allowed.')(\s*/)?&gt;~i','<$1$2$3>',$match);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have decided to just not allow any HTML to render so it'll be easier to have the code thing.

Comment: So better stick with `htmlentities`.