# How to escape code in <code> tag with php htmlentities, even if tag has attributes

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-replace, xss

So someone actually posted a fantastic solution here [How can I escape all code within <code></code> tags to allow people to post code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509447/how-can-i-escape-all-code-within-code-code-tags-to-allow-people-to-post-code)

The problem is that this only works if it's `<code></code>`. However, this breaks with `<code id="lol"></code` for example, since it contains an attribute. How can I account for this, in order to strictly escape strings inside the code tag, whether or not it has any attributes.

I apologize if there is an obvious solution to this. Regexes give me nightmares.

**Edit**

As I explained in the question initially, the post that is supposedly a duplicate does not account for the `<code>` tag with something like a class or any other attributes.

Comment: the answer is already there inside http://stackoverflow.com/a/9509581/3859027

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape all code within <code></code> tags to allow people to post code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509447/how-can-i-escape-all-code-within-code-code-tags-to-allow-people-to-post-code)

Comment: Are you joking me Nicolas? I linked to that question, but it is not the right answer. I'm honestly not sure if you're trolling me.

Comment: [This isn't something I'd recommend solving with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Might I recommend getting a nice HTML parser instead?

Comment: I just need it for a very simple task. I also fully control the data, so I don't have any xss worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of my comment above, I'll endeavour to provide a regex for you to use. I would, however, emphatically ***not*** recommend doing this with regexes, but using an HTML parser instead.

Your regex should look a bit like this:

```
<\s*code(.*?)>(.+?)<\s*\/code\s*>
```

To break it down a bit,

`\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

`code` matches the literal string "`code`".

`.*?` is a *lazy* match of zero or more characters. It will match everything (if anything) up to the end of the tag.

`(.+?)` is a *capture group*, containing a lazy match of one or more characters. If nothing else, your `<code>` tags will never be completely blank (as there must be at least one character between them).

And, finally, `<\s*\/code\s*>` matches the ending tag, with the possibility of included whitespace. Note that the slash (`/`) character is escaped, as it has to be in just about every regex flavour under the sun.

Comment: Did the trick, boss. And I do agree with you. Every other project I would use a parser. I just wanted a simple solution for this case, even though it's technically not "correct"

Comment: One small detail, Sebastion. How can my replacement string retain the attribute value(s)?

Comment: @lazyboy78: Edited. I added another capture group to the opening tag that'll grab any attributes it has.